# Godot online multiplayer

Tags: godot, gdscript

There is a simple game with multiplayer, but the multiplayer will only work in the local network or on devices with a dedicated IP-address. Is it possible to make multiplayer over the Internet. As I understand it, you need to write a relay server for this or is there another way.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You need some kind of server, yes. Authoritative or not. Yours or third party.

Comment: @Theraot I misspoke, the game is not multiplayer, but cooperative. One player has to act as a server of the game and the second to be a client.
As I understand it, you need to use the following scheme: PC 1 (Host) -><- Relay Server -><- PC 2 (Client).

Comment: Cooperative is multiplayer. If you want one of the players to be the server/host for a session, by default you will be limited to LAN. Possibly players could use VPNs or port forwarding to bypass that. You can also add a NAT hole punching solution. But even then there would be many cases where players can't connect, and would need a relay server. Still, that relay server could be programmed and deployed by you, or by a third party (you still need to integrate it in your game). For starters, you can use WebRTC. Other options include using Discord and Steam SDKs. I'm sure there are more options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UPnP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play). Here is an example code:

```
var upnp = UPNP.new()
var err = upnp.discover()
if err == OK:
    if upnp.get_gateway() and upnp.get_gateway().is_valid_gateway():
        upnp.get_gateway().add_port_mapping(PORT, PORT, "GAME_NAME Multiplayer", "UDP")
        upnp.get_gateway().add_port_mapping(PORT, PORT, "GAME_NAME Multiplayer", "TCP")
else:
    push_error("UPNP error: %d" % err)
```

This code should only run for the server. One disadvantage of UPnP is, that is must be enabled on the router, so only peoples that have UPnP enabled, can host a multiplayer game over the full internet (Other can host too, but for they it only works in the LAN).

> Sorry for my bad English.

My english is bad too.

Code from https://github.com/JanoSemi/VoxelFun/blob/main/scripts/Network.gd